# How to vertical align my images and texts

Tags: html, css

I am trying to do a vertical align for my texts and images.

It seems the texts are aligned to top in my jsfiddle

```
text here      --
              |  |
               --
```

I want to have my text to be like

```
               --
text here     |  |
               --
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wjPxS/

I can't really change my image float right in css. Can anyone help me about it? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing as you know the height of your container you can just set the `line-height` the same as `height` to vertically align the text.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZhVzY/1/)

```
.div1 {
    height: 20px;
    line-height:20px;
}
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't work properly if the text wraps at all.

Comment: Everytime you rely on the pixel height of another element in CSS, god kills a kitten.

Comment: I agree, this is relying on the height of the same element though.

Answer (score 0):

**[updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wjPxS/1/)**

You need to apply

```
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
```

to both `img` and `span`. In jsfiddle I replaced `span` with `div'.

Though, this doesn't let you float the `img` to the right.