# How to vertical align images and texts

Tags: html, css

I have a question regarding the vertical align issue

I asked a question yesterday

[How to vertical align my images and texts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19014938/how-to-vertical-align-my-images-and-texts)

but I have changed the codes and texts. The texts inside span has 2 lines of texts and I am not sure how to vertical align middle for image and texts.

I have set `vertical-align` to `middle` on most of the element but still not working

My jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/wjPxS/4/

Can anyone help me about it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it.

For this **HTML**:

```
<div class='div1'>
    <span class='title'> this is the text<br>this is the second text</span>
    <a class='link' href='#'>
        <img class='img' src='http://placehold.it/100x50'/>
    </a>
</div>
```

try the following **CSS**:

```css
.div1 {
    border-color: black;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 1px 1px 1px;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: .8em;
    height: auto;
}
.title {
    width: 200px;
    height: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
.img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

If you use `display: inline-block` for `.title`, you will get better results, otherwise, the alignment will take place with respect to the second line of the `.title` block.

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/mqwzU/

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/9VRxn/2/) to demonstrate how to vertically align everything withing anything.
it also works with 2 line of text, and pretty much everything you want.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="Container">
    <div class="Content">
        I'm the Content
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
    .Container:before
    {
        content: '';
        height: 100%;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

.Content
{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

### Your Fiddle

Here is an updated [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/wjPxS/29/) just for your case. (@Marc Audet: I used your image)